# Which conditions apply to dbdelta column names when creating a table?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I heard that dbdelta is really picky and the most important conditions are described on this site: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

I tried to create a custom table in the wordpress database and used `var_dump($wpdb->last_error);` for debugging purposes.

This was the error message I received:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'group VARCHAR(30) NULL, cat VARCHAR(30) NULL, ' at line 3"

Just for fun I changed the column name group to grou and then I received another error message:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc VARCHAR(255) NULL, mety VARCHAR(7), date ' at line 6"

I changed "desc" to "des" and suddenly it worked. I'm really glad it finally worked but I still want to know why it didn't work with the column names "group" and "desc". Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

This is a <strike>little</strike> very late, but the issue that you're having is mostly unrelated to `dbDelta()`.

In MySQL,`group` and `desc` are keywords: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html. If you want to use those names, you have to quote them with backticks (``). However, it's often easier to use a different name, since otherwise you'll have to quote them every time you use them.

However, when using `dbDelta()`…

> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.

(according to
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).

So you can't use reserved names at all with `dbDelta()`, so you'll have to change them if you want to use it.